# using wget to get the result of google translate

Tags: linux, bash, wget

everybody. I want to write a bash-script to use the google translate from the terminal and translate the English into Chinese. My plan is first use the wget to translate the English,then use sed to get the result. So i use
`wget -qO- --header="Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" --header="Accept-Charset:GBK,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3" --header="Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch" --header="Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4" -U "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.27 Safari/536.11" http://translate.google.cn/#en/zh-CN/hello | gunzip > out.html`.
And i also just tried `wget -U "Mozilla/5.0" http://translate.google.cn/#en/zh-CN/hello`.
Both the results of them seem not what i want, because i can't find `你好` in Chinese from the result.
What's the problem with me?

Comment: http://translate.google.com/robots.txt  Use the [API](https://developers.google.com/translate/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're doing wrong is that you're actually only requesting http://translate.google.cn/ from the server and not http://translate.google.cn/#en/zh-CN/hello. This is because [the part after the hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) doesn't get sent to the server and is only supposed to be used by the browser. Google uses this part to make the translation request using Javascript.

To get the translation you need to make a request to the URL that the Javascript on that page uses. Something like this would work:

```
curl -A "Mozilla/5.0" 'http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t?client=t&text=hello&hl=en&sl=en&tl=zh-CN&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&multires=1&prev=btn&ssel=0&tsel=0&sc=1'
```

The previous command will print the following result:

```
[[["你好","hello","Nǐ hǎo",""]],[["interjection",["喂"],[["喂",["hello","hey"],,0.0087879393]]]],"en",,[["你好",[5],0,0,1000,0,1,0]],[["hello",4,,,""],["hello",5,[["你好",1000,0,0],["招呼",0,0,0],["打招呼",0,0,0],["个招呼",0,0,0],["喂",0,0,0]],[[0,5]],"hello"]],,,[["en"]],6]
```

You can then use sed to obtain the result as follows:

```
curl -A "Mozilla/5.0" 'http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t?client=t&text=hello&hl=en&sl=en&tl=zh-CN&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&multires=1&prev=btn&ssel=0&tsel=0&sc=1' | sed 's/\[\[\["\([^"]*\).*/\1/'
```

However, as others have mentioned you should not be using this to abuse the translate service, and for anything beyond experimentation or CLI-badassery you should (and probably have to) use the [Google Translate API](https://developers.google.com/translate/) to avoid getting yourself in trouble. Google monitors usage, and will most definitely detect any attempts to abuse their services.

P.S: I'm not qualified to give legal advice, and what I wrote above regarding what I consider to be "not abusing the service" is 100% personal opinion, so please don't take it as the final say in the matter.

Comment: Also, another reason why you shouldn't use this method is that, obviously, the internals of how the service works are subject to change, and you never know when your shell script will stop working.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just want to train my skill of write bash-script. And this have some problem,for example: if i want to translate `thank you`,if i just replace the `hello` in  `http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t?client=t&text=hello&hl=en&sl=en&tl=zh-CN&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&multires=1&prev=btn&ssel=0&tsel=0&sc=1`  with `thank you`, it will response Error 400, how can i solve the problem?

Comment: The error is because you have a space in the URL, which must be encoded. Google URL encoding, or read the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) to learn more about it.

Comment: Sorry, I pressed enter and the comment was posted before I finished. But basically, you should replace all your spaces with `%20`, for example `you are welcome` would be `you%20are%20welcome` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have the rights to make those requests. The Google Translate service has an [API](https://developers.google.com/translate/) that you have to pay for. If I try your request using `curl` I get something like the following:

```
<!-- Headers... -->
<ins>That’s an error.</ins>
<p>Your client does not have permission to get URL <code>/</code> from this server.
(Client IP address: xx.xxx.xx.xx)<br><br>


<ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```